# The CentOS7.2 yum can not find the `libc-client-devel`

Tags: centos, yum

The CentOS7.2 yum can not find the `libc-client-devel`.

```
# yum install -y libc-client-devel 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                                                     | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                   | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                  | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
webtatic                                                                                 | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.zju.edu.cn
 * extras: mirrors.zju.edu.cn
 * updates: mirrors.zju.edu.cn
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
No package libc-client-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fedora 26: I'm try to install `libc-client-devel`

```
yum install -y libc-client-devel
```

This is my output:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:00 ago on Thu 20 Sep 2018 06:46:58 AM MSK.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package              Arch          Version                Repository      Size
================================================================================
Installing:
uw-imap-devel        x86_64        2007f-14.fc26          updates         57 k
Installing dependencies:
libc-client          x86_64        2007f-14.fc26          updates        563 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
```

So, try it:

```
yum install -y uw-imap-devel libc-client
```

Comment: why replaced to this?

Comment: @fanhualuojin154873 I don't know